# Why is Xcode showing my variable value as @"0 objects"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My object is not an array nor is it empty. I've tried playing with the Auto/Local option but that does not seem to do anything.

Header file for TopCode:

```
@interface TopCode : NSObject
{
   /* Symbol's id code or -1 if invalid */
   int code;

   /* Width of a single ring in pixels */
   double unit;

   /* Angular orientation of the topcode in radians */
   double orientation;
}

@property (assign) BOOL used;
@property (assign) double x;
@property (assign) double y;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString* string;

- (void)setText;
- (NSString *)description;

-(id) init;
-(double) getCenterX;
-(double) getCenterY;
-(double) getOrientation;
-(int) getCode;
-(void) setCode:(int)c;
-(void) setCenter:(double)cx cy:(double)cy;
-(double) getDiameter;
-(void) setDiameter:(double)d;
-(double) getRadius;
-(void) setRadius:(double)r;
-(BOOL) isValid;
-(BOOL) contains:(double)tx ty:(double)ty;
-(void) draw:(cv::Mat &)image;
-(int) decode:(cv::Mat &)image;
-(NSString *) toJSON;

#define WHEN_CODE 279
#define ENEMY_CODE 205
#define WALL_CODE 157
#define ISCLOSE_CODE 171
#define ISNOTINFRONT_CODE 283
#define ISFAR_CODE 331
#define ISINFRONT_CODE 31
#define MOVE_CODE 211
#define ROTATE_CODE 167
#define RIGHT_CODE 107
#define LEFT_CODE 47
#define FORWARD_CODE 333
#define BACKWARD_CODE 285
#define SHOOT_CODE 213
#define TENINCHES_CODE 109
#define FIVEINCHES_CODE 55
#define TWOINCHES_CODE 339
#define ONEINCH_CODE 295
#define ONEEIGHTYDEGREE_CODE 217
#define NINETYDEGREE_CODE 173
#define FORTYFIVEDEGREE_CODE 115
#define TENDEGREE_CODE 59

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Post .h file for TopCode class.

Comment: Ignore the debugger output.  Use NSLog or `po` in the console.

Comment: I know that I can just use po, but I was looking for something more convenient.

Comment: You want convenient or correct?

Comment: Preferably both? I am also trying to understand why this is happening. I have never experienced anything like this.

Comment: It's fairly common for the debugger variable display to lie, so one should first verify that what you think you're seeing is "real".

Comment: You need to click the check mark to mark responses a answered.  You havent marked any responses as answered for any of your questions you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have that Class name defined in some other file as a variable thats a list.  For Example: if I have a Subject class, and later on I create an NSArray *Subject, I have now redefined the Symbol.

Refactor the class TopCode to TopCodeLink or whatever and you will resolve the issue. Or find the NSArray named TopCode and change it

Comment: It works but the issue keeps coming back! I have to change the class name every time to see the values in debugger's output.

Answer (score 1):

Lost a day on this one. It is a BUG in the XCode debugger. I use XCode 6.2. It stops showing object reference and data and instead it is just "0 objects". Use NSLog to check the object and its values and they should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me to fix this issue was quitting and restarting `XCode`.